# tkfiledialog gives a ridiculous small window on new computer

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I use:

```
root = Tk()
root.fileName=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
```

to input data in many of my python programs. Now I got a new computer and all seems to work except the size of the window for to open the files. It is there, and it is correct, but microscopic in size!! This have something to do with the screen resolution, but how can it be fixed?

[image]

The computer is a Dell XPS 15 and I use Ubuntu 18.04

Does any have had the same problem?

Greetings!
Per

Answer (score 0):

I did not get any answers so I tried wx instead and it worked out fine.
Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Greetings! Per

Answer (score -1):

To modify the size of the window you can use `geometry` like so:

```
root.geometry("500x800")
```

This would make a window of 500 width and 800 height.

Comment: @PerPersson you should specify more clearly in your answer that the text is what you want to enlarge.To do so, I would try font='Verdana, 30'

Comment: Well it is both, I added a screenshot. How do one change the fontsize of the such windows?